# single certificate to use multiple tomcat instances on single server

Tags: java, tomcat8

Can we use single certificate issued to a server that has two tomcats hosted which is running on 8080 and 8081 ports. Now, if I wanted to use SSL how should I proceed
.
FYI
Tomcat8-64
java8-64
windows server2012 r2
I'm using currently
http://devserver:8080/
http://devserver:8081/

Should I request multiple certificates or just one certificate and install on java cacerts. use same jvm.dll for both tomcats?
-what changes should I make server.xml on two tomcats
I want both on secure https
can I use
https://devserver:8443/
https://devserver:8444/
or pls suggest me

Comment: Certificates are driven by host name, not port number, so yes, you can share the certificate across multiple instances/ports on the same host. I think you can even use the same JKS file if you set up your server.xml properly.

Comment: @rmlan Which AFAIK is something that generally has to be enabled, not something most clients do by default. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62900/do-ssl-x-509-certs-cover-all-ports-for-a-host

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480760/ssl-certificates-in-tomcat-server    I found this link. which ports can I use for multiple https ports for ultiple instances?

Comment: Can I use like this for   https://devserver:8443/   &  https://devserver:8444/  multiple instances?

Comment: Yes, you can. Technically, you can use any port number as long as the client is set up to use an SSL protocol, e.g. by specifying `https`.

Comment: Some further info: documentation for Tomcat's server.xml and how to set up HTTPS on a `<Connector>` can be found [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File), and if you run into issues, feel free to update your question or ask a new question about any particular problems you run into. The question you linked gives a pretty good example of the `<Connector>` setup, and JKS setup instructions can also be found in the Tomcat documentation that I linked (see the `keytool` commands).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. one last thing that confuses me is after importing certificate into cacert keystore do I still need to specify the path & password of the certificate location in the server.xml in <connector??

Comment: You'll need to provide your certificate's alias inside the keystore as well as the certificate password, yes. These are the `keyAlias` and `keyPass` attributes on your `<Connector>`, and their descriptions and defaults are documented [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html).

Comment: @rmlan: can you identify an example? I've never seen any cert containing a port number, and since CAs switched to prefer SAN over CN about a decade ago it isn't even possible to represent port in an SSL/TLS cert; and I've never seen any client fail to accept the same cert on all ports if it accepts the cert at all.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I cannot at the moment, and perhaps I am completely misremembering. I recall at some point running a server on port 8443 being an issue for hostname checking, but I am inclined to believe you and Brian